# DELETE statement in sql taking too long to execute

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I have a sql delete query which invovles deleting 15k records.
the following is the format:

```
query += """ DELETE FROM table1
            WHERE attr1 IN (SELECT distinct attr2
                                         FROM table2
                                         WHERE condition1 = %d
                                         AND condition2 = %d);
        """ %(val1, val2)
```

This IN operator takes a lot of time.
Kindly suggest how i can convert it into a JOIN which will take less time to execute.

Comment: You don't need the distinct in the inner query. What does the execution plan say? Where do you lose the performance? Which DBMS is this?

Comment: are you sure the delete is not slow because of triggers, but because of the `in` operator - `select * from table1 ...` is equaly slow?

Comment: I am using postgres. Only this abbove delete statement gets stuck when the script is run. I dont know how.. The syntax seems to be correct. if i directly fire it in the db, it works... however through script its getting stuck.

Comment: Please post the execution plan (ideally as a link to http://explain.depesz.com/)

Comment: when you print the query is it the same as when you fire it directly???

Comment: I have a doubt dat its slow because of IN... and dats y i was wondering if i can change it to a JOIN. I tried different join formats but its not working . Please suggest a better way.

Comment: Yes.. its the same.. but i fire directly for 1 device... n through script, i fire the query for 15K devices together.

Comment: If "through script its getting stuck" then I assume there is some locking going on. Check out pg_locks and see if that script is waiting for some other session to finish.

Answer (score 2):

Use `JOIN` instead on `IN` operator and create indexes on fields used in Joining condition.

```
DELETE FROM table1 using table2 Where attr1  = attr2 And condition1 = %d AND condition2 = %d;
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if Postgres created the same execution plan for the IN and JOIN solution. The optimizer is pretty smart about these kind of things.

Comment: I tried the statement DELETE FROM table1 using table2 On attr1  = attr2 And condition1 = %d AND condition2 = %d; but it gives me error at "On".

Comment: @user977933, I typed ON at place of Where. Now try the corrected answer.

Comment: There is also the WHERE EXISTS (...) variant (which would probably also generate the same plan)

Answer (score 1):

Remove Distinct from the sub query and in the IN clause. Instead use Where EXISTS.
Your Distinct will cause an Internal Order by, which will consume more time.

And also index table1.attr1 and table2.attr2.

```
query += """ DELETE FROM table1
        WHERE Exists (SELECT null 
                                     FROM table2
                                     WHERE condition1 = %d
                                     AND condition2 = %d
                                     and table2.attr2 = table1.attr1);
    """ %(val1, val2)
```

Comment: PostgreSQL will only use a sort if the result is very large. Otherwise it will use a hashing algorithm for the distinct. But in general I agree the DISTINCT is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding indexes in `attr1`, `condition1` and `condition2` columns to improve performance.

Comment: do you mean 1 index for attr1 and 2nd for condition1 and condition2?